# Mysql Partition that will delete data that is 30 days older

Tags: mysql, database-partitioning

Mysql table structure is as follows :

```
CREATE TABLE `golden` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `query` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `store` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `augment` longtext NOT NULL,
  `intent` longtext NOT NULL,
  `parsed_query` longtext NOT NULL,
  `query_store` longtext NOT NULL,
  `FSN` longtext,
  `updated_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `myIndex` (`query`,`updated_at`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1837 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

This table gets populated with 5000 queries everyday. Need a way to partition the data on 'updated_at' so that it will have only 60 days data and older data will get auto deleted.

Fairly new to this whole mysql partitions. Please help!

Comment: Create a process that will delete data older than 60 days and set in the cron to run it daily.

Comment: Have a requirement to use partition itself. :(

Comment: May be this will help you http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-triggers/working-mysql-scheduled-event/

Comment: Are you certan you need to use partitioning for that? Partitions do not autodelete, you still need to delete them. Partitioning has some disadvantages, and they have to be outweighted by the advantages. The advantage here is that you can delete a complete partition very fast, but it might not be worth the trouble to be able to delete 5000 rows in 0.01ms instead of 3s once a day. Also, *if* partitioning is used for this, it is usally a monthly thing (e.g. keep the last 3 month, which is ~60 days on the 1st and ~90 days on the 30th/31th). Could you clarify if that is ok?

Comment: @Solarflare Yes I need these partitions deleted every 3 months.  And one 3-month partition will have around 4.5 lakh records. i want to partition my DB on 3 months.